# Масштабирование элементов QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Пытаюсь создать графический редактор на Qt. Добавил на сцену графические элементы QGraphicsItem на сцену QGraphicsScene. Нужно сделать функцию масштабирования этих элементов. На форме создал меню с действиями, по щелчку на которые должно совершаться масштабирование. Прикреплен код функции класса сцены, который именно и описывает, как я пытаюсь осуществить масштабирование.

```
void PaintScene::scaleObject(const qreal Scala){

foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, selectedItems()){
    QTransform itTransf = item->transform();
    QPointF dp = item->boundingRect().center();
    itTransf.translate( dp.x(), dp.y());
    itTransf *= QTransform::fromScale(Scala, Scala);
    itTransf.translate( -dp.x(),  -dp.y());
    item->setTransform(itTransf);
    item->update();}
 }
```

Проблема в том, что используя приведенный код, у меня масштаб элементов вроде как изменяется, но они при этом съезжают. Видимо, проблема с координатами, т. е. как будто бы изменяется масштаб сцены. Не могу разобраться в чем дело. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать. Заранее спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить флаг `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` для item

```
#ifndef MAINWIN_H
#define MAINWIN_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPushButton>

#include <QGraphicsObject>
#include <QGradient>
#include <QPen>

class Rect : public QGraphicsObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QPointF position READ pos WRITE setPos)

public:
    Rect() : m_draw_rect(QRectF())
    {
    }

    void set_draw_rect(const QRectF& _draw_rect)
    {
        m_draw_rect = _draw_rect;
    }

    QRectF boundingRect() const override
    {
        //origin at 0,0 top left
        return m_draw_rect;
    }

    void paint(QPainter *_painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *_option, QWidget *_widget = Q_NULLPTR) override
    {
        _painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
        _painter->drawRoundRect(boundingRect(), 0, 0);
    }

protected:
    QRectF m_draw_rect;
};

class mainwin : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    mainwin(QWidget *parent = 0)
    {
        QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                Rect* rect = new Rect();
                rect->set_draw_rect(QRect(0, 0, 30, 30));
                rect->setPos(QPoint(i * 100, j * 100));
                rect->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);

                if (j==0)
                    rect->setSelected(true);

                scene->addItem(rect);
            }
        }


        QGraphicsView* view_widget = new QGraphicsView();
        view_widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
        view_widget->setScene(scene);

        setCentralWidget(view_widget);

        setFixedSize(640, 480);

        QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton("Scale", this);

        QObject::connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [scene]
        {
            qreal scale = 1.4;
            foreach(QGraphicsItem *item, scene->selectedItems())
            {
                item->setScale(scale);
                item->update();             
            }
        });
    }
};

#endif // MAINWIN_H
```